# Inject two SQLite db and use their repositories C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project and I need to have two SQLite Connection. I'm using Autofac 3.5.2

I Have a global `IRepository<TEntity>` :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        Task<int> AddAsync(TEntity entity);
        Task<int> DeleteAsync(TEntity entity);
    }
```

I decide to create an abstract class to manage the `IRepository<TEntity>` interface commonly :

```
public abstract class BaseRepository <TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection Connection { get; }

        public BaseRepository(SQLiteAsyncConnection connection)
        {
            Connection = connection;
        }

        public async Task<int> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            return await Connection.InsertAsync(entity);
        }

        public async Task<int> DeleteAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            return await Connection.DeleteAsync(entity);
        }
}
```

And after that I wan't to instantiate my two SQLiteConnections :

The first :

```
public class SQLiteRepositoryFirst<TEntity> : BaseRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        public SQLiteRepositoryFirst(SQLiteAsyncConnection connection) : base(connection)
        {

        }
    }
```

The second :

```
public class SQLiteRepositorySecond<TEntity> : BaseRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        public SQLiteRepositorySecond(SQLiteAsyncConnection connection) : base(connection)
        {

        }
    }
```

Using Autofac I have inject it like this :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseRepository<>))
                   .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
                   .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<DatabaseConfiguration>()
                   .As<IDatabaseConfiguration>()
                   .SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(connect => new SQLiteAsyncConnection(
                connect.Resolve<IDatabaseConfiguration>().GetFirstConnectionPath()))
                   .As<SQLiteAsyncConnection>().SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(connect => new SQLiteAsyncConnection(
                connect.Resolve<IDatabaseConfiguration>(). GetSecondConnectionPath()))
                  .As<SQLiteAsyncConnection>().SingleInstance();
```

The DatabaseConfiguration class is where I get the path of my two string path databases.

Now I wan't to use my repository like this:

```
 IRepository<HouseEntity> HouseRepository { get; }
```

But it's not working, the problem is that I don't know how to make the difference between the two db connections when I use a repository. So the application don't know in which database I need to take the data.

EDIT :
It looks like I also have a problem for the abstract class injection.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong ?